# Using ModelBuilder to select identical attributes in all other file geodatabase features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, iterator

I have several datasets that all have the same reference number in them (this is an as-built CAD number). These can be points, lines and polygons. I am attempting to build a model that would select that reference number across all feature datasets in any given .gdb and highlight them in the map (making a selection set). I have spent most of the day playing with iterators but have so far come up short.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to model this so a user would only have to enter that reference number as a parameter and then run the tool to see all highlighted features in their map with that corresponding number?

Comment: ModelBuilder isn't really the right framework for this sort of task.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to break this into at least two models, as you are going to need 2 different iterators: Iterate Datasets and Iterate Feature Classes.
Personally I might even break it into three models. The top model iterates the dataset,[image: Model 1:Iterate Datasets], the second model iterates the feature classes[image: Model 2: Iterate Feature Classes] and the third model does the selection